# Solutions to exercises in Nelsen's “An Introduction to Copulas”

Tags: copula

I am paving my way through Roger Nelsen's "An Introduction to Copulas".

The book has exercises (quite good actually), but no solutions.

Does anybody have a solution manual for (some of those) exercises?

Also references to Copula related (intro level) problem sets with solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: *Nelsen's* book? Did you try [contacting the author](http://legacy.lclark.edu/~mathsci/nelsen.html) directly?

Comment: Not yet, do you think he would take time to answer?

Comment: @Sergey: it is hard for me to say, but I think a polite, concise, personalized e-mail is likely to receive some response. He has obvious interests in the pedagogy of mathematics.

Comment: I will try, will let you know about any success.

Comment: @Sergey: That would be great!

Comment: @cardinal If I contacted the author, and the author gave it to me, I would upload it for everyone to use. Assuming everyone thinks the same way, if it is not found online, either NO ONE has ever contacted the author before or the author does not give it out to just anyone. So what would be the point of contacting the author?

Comment: @SergeyZykov Try reaching him. He is one of the approachable professors we can dream of.